# How can I get a value in a list of objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have a list of objects

```
{
    "Anne": { age: 3, country: "USA" },
    "Flex": { age: 5, country: "UK" }
}
```

How can I get an array of country?
I can use Object.Values. How about in nested object in javascript?

```
["USA","UK"]
```

Comment: Related: [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865/218196)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Object.values(input).map(it => it.country)
```

You could map the objects to their countries.